# Pegar os valores gradient do background separados e salvar em um novo array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com esses atributos de background de um elemento:

```
"background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(0.25turn, rgb(117, 117, 117), rgb(46, 184, 46), rgb(21, 21, 21), rgb(166, 166, 166)) repeat scroll 0% 0%;"
```

Como posso pegar as 4 cores diferentes do gradient e separa-las em um array dessa forma:

```
  [117,117,117],[46,184,46],[21,21,21],[45,175,230],[166,166,166],
```

Acho que a maneira que estou tentando está errada:
(Deixei bem dividido para entender melhor)

```js
    var colorsP = "background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(0.25turn, rgb(117, 117, 117), rgb(46, 184, 46), rgb(21, 21, 21), rgb(166, 166, 166)) repeat scroll 0% 0%;"

    colorsP = colorsP.split('0.25turn, ');
    colorsP = colorsP[1];
    colorsP = colorsP.split(') ');
    colorsP = colorsP[0];
    colorsP = colorsP.split('rgb');
    colorsP = colorsP.filter((value)=>value!='');
    
    console.log(colorsP);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que isso resolve seu problema:
Utilizando uma expressão regular para identificar o conteudo de cada `rgb(R,G,B)`, em que R, G e B são valores numéricos:

A partir desses, iterar por cada string `rgb(R, G, B)` e usar outra ER para identificar valores numéricos.
Após isso, iterar pelos resultados e colocar cada um em um array.

Por fim, criar um array, com os arrays anteriores.

```js
const er = new RegExp(/rgb\(.*?\)/gi); //ER que identifica os textos 'rgb(R, G, B)'
const texto = "background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(0.25turn, rgb(117, 117, 117), rgb(46, 184, 46), rgb(21, 21, 21), rgb(166, 166, 166)) repeat scroll 0% 0%;"; // o texto completo

matches = [... texto.matchAll(er)]; //criando um vetor com os resultados encontrados no texto completo

valores = matches.map(function(v){ // passando por cada string do vetor acima (que tem o conteúdo similar a 'rgb(R, G, B)'
    erV = new RegExp(/\d+/g); //criando uma ER para identficar os números dentro do texto atual
    resultados = [... v[0].matchAll(erV)]; // encontrando todos 
    arrayRetorno = resultados.map(function(vr){ //passando por cada um deles e...
         return parseInt(vr[0]); // ... retornando como números inteiros
    })
    return arrayRetorno; // devolvendo o vetor atual para o 'vetor de vetores'
}); 

console.log(valores);
```

Irá resultar em:

```
[[117, 117, 117], [46, 184, 46], [21, 21, 21], [166, 166, 166]]
```

Lembre-se que qualquer alteração que afete o padrão `rbg(R, G, B)`  (por exemplo de `rgb(0,0,0)` para `#000000`) irá causar falhas.

Comment: Obrigado Marcos, você matou a pau. Preciso aprender mais sobre expressões regulares pois não consegui entender nada de como você identificou os caracteres. Você sabe me dizer porque a pergunta foi tão negativada? É uma pergunta ruim ? Foi a forma que escrevi ? Ou a minha solução estava tão distante que merecia mesmo ?

Comment: Disponha, estamos aqui para ajudar.
Sobre as ER, no começo é meio assustador mesmo, mas um pouco de treino e leitura, rapidamente você pega o jeito. Sugiro que use o https://regexr.com/ para brincar com isso. Lá tem um pouco de explicação e você consegue ver na hora o funcionamento das ER.
Sobre a negativação da pergunta, é muito subjetivo, cada voto vem de uma pessoa e cada uma com um ponto de vista. Em todo caso, leia as ajudas do site, principalmente a parte das perguntas que oferecem ótimas dicas.

Comment: Valeu Marcão, vou dar uma olhada! Dei uma editada na pergunta, acho que ficou melhor. Abraço.